# Can a story be considered plagarism even though its in a different world

Tags: fiction, plagiarism

If there are two works with the same character name and family type can it be considered a plagiarized work even though the plot is different?  One work is about two brothers raised by their father to  be supernatural hunters trying to find their mothers killer.  the other is about two brothers raised by their parents to be killers for  hire trying to survive their abusive dysfunctional marriage.

Comment: Note that apart from copyright considerations, you may also run into trademark issues.

Answer (score 7):

Names of characters are typically protected by copyright. (I say typically because some very generic names used in many works, like "John Doe", are not attributable to any single original work).

So yes, it would be plagiarism. I cannot create a character named "Harry Potter" and write some other kind of story about him. The fact that you make your "family type" the same would just help to prove you really were plagiarizing that particular character.

I presume you are trying to piggy-back on the fame of some particular famous character in order create "automatic" interest for your work, but that is profiting off of the original author's imagination and marketing money spent, precisely what the copyright law is intended to protect. JK Rowling (and her assigned business partners) are the ONLY people allowed to profit from the name "Harry Potter". (Similarly for whatever name you intended to steal.)

Use your own imagination, and come up with your own fictional name.

Comment: No  actually  I just like the  first  name. as for  the  family  type  I didnt mean to   that  was accidental  . I normally use the  family  type  in  question  .  As for  piggy backing no  Iam not  even  sure if  I am  going to  publish  it  Its  just  my   calming writing  I am just  learning my  own  style  and I write for comfort but one never knows so its best  to  be careful. I would  like  to  thank  you for   you  answer though

Comment: If a single name is unique to an author (and not a word that appears in any other work, like a dictionary), it is copyrighted. For example, I would think "Darth" (as a title of a Sith Lord in the Star Wars universe) would be copyrighted, it does not appear in my giant book of names. (It could conceivably be an actual word in a foreign language; in which case I'm not certain if copyright can apply).